# Database Project on TFS using synonym to another database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs

I have a database project on TFS using Visual Studio 2015.
In my project I created a synonym that is pointed to another db on the same server. When I try to compile the project, is telling me that has an unresolved reference pointed to the synonym object.

How can I handle this to get TFS compiled?

I checked this link: [Visual Studio 2010 Database Project - Unresolved Reference to a Synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642874/visual-studio-2010-database-project-unresolved-reference-to-a-synonym)

But looks like this is working only when we have two or more projects on the same solution. In my case I have different DB projects, so when I try to compile I have this error:

[dbo].[ProviderContact].[ProviderUserId] contains an unresolved reference to an object. 
Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[LookupUser].[u]::[UserId], [dbo].[LookupUser].[UserId] 
or [dbo].[UserProviderRelation].[u]::[UserId].

The view that refers to the synonym (dbo.LookupUser) is this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ProviderContact]
AS
    SELECT upr.Id, upr.Name, u.Description, u.UserId AS ProviderUserId, 
      FROM dbo.UserProviderRelation AS upr 
     INNER JOIN dbo.LookupUser AS u 
        ON upr.UserId = u.UserId
     WHERE (u.UserTypeId = 1)
GO
```

The synonym is this:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[LookupUser] FOR [AnotherDB].[dbo].[Users]
GO
```

The synonym is in another database but on the same server.

When I open the Add Database Reference... I see this:

[image]

So I can't add the reference. How can I solve the reference in this case?

Comment: It should be database reference issue, could you please provide the detail steps to reproduce your issue? you can also check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642874/visual-studio-2010-database-project-unresolved-reference-to-a-synonym), maybe it helps.

Comment: You can try to create a DACPAC file for "another" database,then Add Database Reference to your project, please check [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3331/how-to-use-a-linked-server-in-a-sql-server-database-project/) link for details.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you have this issue. I came here because I have a similar issue with 4 notation.

For VS2017 your problem does not seem to hold. Different DB same server.

I use a variable within the project though like this.

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[LookupUser] FOR   FOR [$(Serverdb)].[$(Anothedb)].[dbo].[Users]

Let me know if you need help in setting up the variables with the Project definition in VS.

Leo